# How to avoid classloading conflicts for a java library

Tags: java, classloader

We have a java library (more like a framework) which can be used to build JDBC drivers. The framework implements the JDBC interface, and you implement some interfaces which are consumed by the framework to realize the driver.

One issue which has come up is that if you create two drivers with this framework, and try to use them simultaneously in a single JVM, only a single set of the framework classes will be loaded.

This is bad for at least two reasons:

1. The framework contains singletons, so only the first driver loaded
   actually works correctly.
2. Even if we removed all singletons, things
   could break if the 'wrong version' of the framework is loaded at
   runtime for one of the drivers.

The solution used was to rename the framework class packages for each driver, so that they would no longer conflict. While this works, there is a concern about the bytecode manipulation, as it happens after our testing.

My question: Is there a better way? This needs to be handled from our side, not the application's, as an application uses the driver simply as a JDBC driver, so it needs to be transparent.

One idea I had was to serialize all the classes of the driver (other than the 'entrypoint' classes which implement Driver/DataSource) into some sort of resource which is packaged in the driver jar (with the FQN of the resource and entrypoint classes being unique to the driver), then have the entrypoint classes, in a static initialization block, read out the classes and load them with a private classloader. Are there any glaring problems I'm missing with this approach?

Comment: Not the answer, but I can't understand why you (or your framework) want to generate the drivers with the same packages . It is like having a Postgresql driver using com.mysql.jdbc, for working with both databases at the same time: I can imagine an application using dedicated classloaders, but would be a mess anyway.

Comment: Drivers are registered for the whole JVM, so you cannot have 2 drivers with the same FQN

Comment: @DBE - We write the framework, and sell it to others who use it to create their own driver. What we create has given package names, so if nothing is done, two drivers written by different customers can conflict due to the framework classes.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev - The drivers themselves have different FQNs, it's just that (some) of the classes they depend on may not be unique, due to the presence of other drivers.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Java [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)? It is a bit cumbersome to use, but if you made your various Driver implementations named service providers, then perhaps your users can utilize that mechanism in their apps.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade - We don't have control of how the end user will use the driver. It should act as a 'normal' JDBC driver.

Comment: If I understand, you need to have more than one version of some stateful singletons (for every driver.) This contradicts the very definition of the singletons, with the exception of your frameworks loading their singletons with a dedicated classloader as you mention. This is similar to the versioning done in OSGI and should work. I don't understand the "serialization" thing you mention: just loading the singleton's jar with different children classloader instances should do the trick.

Comment: @DBE -  singletons aren't even the fundamental problem, if we ignore their existence, you could still get problems with loading the wrong version of a class

Comment: Serializing the classes allows me to load them without referring to them by their FQN (which may not be unique)